# Adding up values for same dates in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query below provides the result in the image, however I want to the sum the **NewOrders** and **DoneOrders** for the same **dates**.Already i'm getting data for the past 7 days.

```
SELECT DATE(pickup_date),
COUNT(CASE WHEN order_status ='New' THEN 1 END) AS "NewOrders",
COUNT(CASE WHEN order_status ='Done' THEN 1 END) AS "DoneOrders" 
from requests where DATE(pickup_date) > current_date::date - INTERVAL '7 days' GROUP BY pickup_date 
ORDER BY pickup_date;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix the `GROUP BY`.  Your aggregation key is the date with the time.  You want to convert the value to a date:

```
SELECT pickup_date::date, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN order_status ='New' THEN 1 END) AS "NewOrders",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN order_status ='Done' THEN 1 END) AS "DoneOrders" 
FROM requests 
WHERE pickup_date::date > current_date- INTERVAL '7 days'
GROUP BY pickup_date::date
ORDER BY pickup_date::date;
```

Postgres also supports `FILTER`, which is a cleaner way to write the logic.  In addition, `current_date` *is* a date, so it does not need to be converted, and double quotes are not needed, so don't use them!

```
SELECT pickup_date::date, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE order_status = 'New') AS NewOrders,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE order_status = 'Done') AS DoneOrders
FROM requests 
WHERE pickup_date::date > current_date - INTERVAL '7 days'
GROUP BY pickup_date::date
ORDER BY pickup_date::date;
```

Comment: I have another column price, but for that one, i have to check when order_status = "Done", I want to add this subquery to it, select sum(price) where order_status = "Done", for the same query

Comment: You can write it like `sum(price) filter (where order_status='Done') as PriceSum` in above query.